# Cron Constantly Running

Tags: php, cron, schedule

I am having issues with cron.php constantly running. I never had an issue with this until I upgraded to Magento CE 1.9.1.1. My hosting provider actually had to disable cron.php because it was causing a high load on the CPU. I installed AOE Scheduler and disabled some tasks which weren't necessary. I then had my hosting provider re-enable access to cron.php. However, cron will not run on the server even though I have a cron job setup correctly. I then decided to manually run the cron job by entering it's address in my internet browser's address bar. Once again, cron.php would constantly run and not stop, causing a high load on the CPU. The only way I could get it to stop was to rename cron.php to something like cron.BAK.

Cron tasks do run when I use AOE Scheduler to run the task immediately. However, I can create a schedule with AOE Scheduler and cron isn't running those tasks because it still isn't being executed by the server.

My question is two fold...

1. How do I find out why cron.php won't stop running? Is this an issue with 1.9.1.1? I never had this issue until I upgraded from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.1.1.
2. Why isn't the server executing the cron job I have setup? Once again, I never had this issue until I upgraded to 1.9.1.1.

Right now, I'm mainly concerned with question #1. Question #2 is a low priority until I can get cron.php to run the tasks it's supposed to run and then stop. It's becoming a real pain because I'm getting hounded by my hosting provider about the high CPU load.

Comment: This is what is showing in my system.log over and over again until I rename cron.php to stop it from running...

2015-05-27T16:00:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec() [<a href='function.shell-exec'>function.shell-exec</a>]: Unable to execute '/bin/sh /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.sh cron.php -mdefault 1 &gt; /dev/null 2&gt;&amp;1 &amp;'  in /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.php on line 64

Comment: And...

2015-05-27T16:00:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec() [<a href='function.shell-exec'>function.shell-exec</a>]: Unable to execute '/bin/sh /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.sh cron.php -malways 1 &gt; /dev/null 2&gt;&amp;1 &amp;'  in /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.php on line 65

Comment: Lines 64 and 65 of cron.php show this...

64 - shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
65 - shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");

Answer (score 3):

You should not call/run cron.php directly but cron.sh via system cronjob/crontab instead.

I can recommend Fabrizios Blogpost for more information about the Magento cron:

**cron.php vs. cron.sh**

> In Magento’s root folder there’s a cron.php file and a cron.sh file.
>   Briefly explained cron.sh internally calls cron.php and takes care of
>   not executing more than one process in parallel. That’s a good thing,
>   right? Well, sometimes… If you have long running tasks (e.g. a product
>   import implemented as a task), these tasks will prevent anything else
>   from being executed until the task has finished. You might have some
>   other important tasks that shouldn’t wait or be skipped just because
>   another task is running. Check the “Missed if Not Run Within” setting
>   to configure the maximum delay a task can have to still be executed.
>
> On the other hand using cron.php will start a new process every time
>   it’s being called which could easily result in performance problems or
>   race conditions for tasks operating on the same data. This is why
>   cron.php should not be called directly. Find out more about cron
>   groups later in this blog post for a nice solution on how to handle
>   this situation.

http://www.webguys.de/magento/tuerchen-08-magento-cron-demystified/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this still doesn't answer my question. I have AOE Scheduler installed and have cleared all of the tasks. Even with nothing scheduled, cron.php just runs and runs. It's like it says I have nothing scheduled, yet there's things running per cron that I can't see.

Answer (score 2):

you need to kill cron, and restart it as in crontab, then install mytop https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mytop/1.9.1-1, to see if there is anything stuck in database, also you need to strace (http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace , http://chadfowler.com/blog/2014/01/26/the-magic-of-strace/ ) cron pid. had this issue before and after we found that cron is trying to run one job too long we used

> **Cron groups**: Split you crons into different groups so you can run them
>   in parallel or distribute them on multiple servers.

and now everything is good.

Comment: I just looked in the cron_schedule table and found it was empty, yet it is still running and causing 85% CPU usage. Any other ideas?